# Pad-to-Resistor trace too long in datasheet layout example (TLV803E)?

Tags: pcb, datasheet, layout, texas-instruments, reset

I'm layouting a board that includes the TLV803EF26DBZR voltage supervisor (or reset IC) chip.

In the datasheet, it is suggested that the IC is layouted in the following manner:

[image: TI Datasheet Layout Example]

However, I wonder if the (reset - Pull-up resistor) and (VDD - Pull-up resistor) connections can also be done by connecting the pad with a straight trace rather than doing the loop suggested in the datasheet (see my layout below):

[image: My layout]

My question is:

Is there a good reason (manufacturability, reliability, etc.) why the layout example is done in this way? or is it just an omission from their part and my layout is just as good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Layout examples like this are simply suggestions, and not meant to show accurate trace widths and component sizes - for example your resitors and capacitors are much larger than in the diagram.

Breaking out the reset traces from the side of the package as you have done is fine. This is not done in the example, likely because it's harder to show as they would run underneath the white box representing the IC.

As this is a supervisor IC montoring VDD, my only suggestion would be to move the trace to the VDD side of the resistor over so it joins at the capacitor as they show, rather than straight off the pin. This will mean that any current flowing through the resistor when the output switches doesn't cause a slightly voltage drop on the trace to the VDD pin. Although given the IC includes hysteresis and a timeout on changes to the VDD level, this is probably unnecessary.

---

<sup>As a side note, unless they are used for something else as well, the number of GND vias there seems a tad excessive.</sup>

Comment: Thank you for your explanation